# How to test 'devtools chrome extension plugin' using google puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I have developed a plugin that is part of google developer tool. It has its own panel in developer tool. It also intercepts request and has some UI for users. I want to automate testing of this plugin. Is there a way to make google puppeteer to open the correct panel of devtools and perform actions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ devtools: true });
const targets = await browser.targets();

// find Devtools target URL
const devtoolsUrl = targets
    .map(({ _targetInfo }) => _targetInfo.url)
    .find((url) => url.indexOf('chrome-devtools://') !== -1);

// load the Devtools page in a new tab
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(devtoolsUrl);

// click on Network tab
const networkTab = await page.evaluateHandle(`document.querySelector('#-blink-dev-tools > div.widget.vbox.root-view > div > div.widget.vbox.insertion-point-sidebar > div > div').shadowRoot.querySelector('#tab-network');`);
await networkTab.click();
```

Based on this [answer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3699#issuecomment-449518851) . I have tried this it was working good, check this [output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/inlxcp09ghe1zft/Screenshot%202018-12-23%2007.40.04.png?dl=0)

Comment: This is just a workaround because it just loads the static panel without data inside. We cannot interact with live panel of the devtools of current page.